# How is the amount of checkpoints in Tower Control determined?

Tags: splatoon-3

I've always thought that there are 3 checkpoints on both sides, but I've played a match today when there were only 2. What was the reason from the reduction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkpoint positions in Tower Control are map-specific. Sturgeon Shipyard is the only map in Splatoon 3 with two checkpoints per team instead of three. I verified this by using Recon Mode to visit all 12 maps.

[image: Sturgeon Shipyard]